Error con Laragon - Python
Tengo instalado laragon y python 3.13 al momento de hacer pip me sale el siguiente error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\laragon\bin\python\python-3.13\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

No deseo instalarlo desde Microsoft Store, me gustaría lograr que funcionara todo desde la consola cmd/Cmder.
Ya tengo las variables de entorno, pero sigue sin funcionar.

C:\laragon\bin\python\python-3.13
C:\laragon\bin\python\python-3.13\Scripts

Agradezco ayduda.

Hola, no he usado nunca Laragon, pero por acotar algunas cosas, ¿Te genera ese mismo error desde la terminal propia de laragon (si es que no la estás usando ya)? ¿Si ejecutas pip como módulo (que es lo recomendable) mediante python -m pip install lo_que_sea o explícitamente  con la ruta absoluta C:\laragon\bin\python\python-3.13\python -m pip install lo_que_sea te genera también una excepción? Si es así, la explicación más simple es que no tengas instalado el módulo pip (que no es lo mismo que el binario de Scripts), puedes intentar instalarlo con python -m ensurepip --upgrade
